# how to draw a stacked bar

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a dataframe - df as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Card_name":['AAA','AAA','AAA','BBB','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC','CCC'],
                   "Amount":['900','800','700','600','500','400','400','300','200'],
                   "Category" :['Grocery','Bank','Gas','Bank','Grocery','Recreation',
                                'Bank','Grocery','Gas']})
```

I want to build a visualization plot, where i can show for all the "**Card_name**" the Categories along with the amount. Maybe a stacked bar chart which shows all the **categories for each "Card_name"**. Each area(size of the area) in the **stacked bar chart depends on the Amount**.
I tried many possible ways but i am not able to visualize ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First pivot your `df`, then call give the option `stacked=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Card_name":['AAA','AAA','AAA','BBB','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC','CCC'],
 "Amount":['900','800','700','600','500','400','400','300','200'],
"Category" :['Grocery','Bank','Gas','Bank','Grocery','Recreation','Bank','Grocery','Gas']})
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'])
df.pivot(index='Card_name', columns='Category', values='Amount').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```